# jQuery showing div and then Disappearing

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I apologize ahead of time if this is a simple question, I have this javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#results").hide();

    var html = $.ajax({ url: "ajax.php?db_list=get", async: false}).responseText;

    $("#submit").click(function () { 
        $("#results").show(); 
    });
});
```

I have a button that looks this:

```
<fieldset class="action">
        <button name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
```

When I click on the Submit button I wanted to show the results div and have it stay there, but in Chrome it pops up and then immediately disappears, is this because of the hide() function at the top of my document ready?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> ...is this because of the hide() function at the top of my document ready?

Probably. I'm guessing the page is refreshing. If you don't want that, use `return false;` in the handler.

```
$("#submit").click(function () { 
    $("#results").show();
    return false; 
});
```

or [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

```
$("#submit").click(function ( event ) { 
    $("#results").show();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Yep thank you this was the problem, return false keeps the div open,

Comment: Thank you, return false did the trick for me (my div would show very quickly, then hide...I was using toggle()). Why is this and why does return false fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Have your results initially set to be hidden via CSS

```
/* CSS */
#results {
  display: none;
}
```

Not sure why you are jumping around the way you should use $.ajax. Use $.get if it's a GET request... Bind with .live because its better :). Let it be async because you don't want your server hanging in case of an error...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').live('click', function(){
    $.get('ajax.php?db_list=get', function(data){
      $('#results').html(data);
      $('#results').show();
      return false;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This really isn't a situation where `.live()` should be used. For a single handler on a single element that is available on page load, you should bind directly.

Comment: the way i read the question, i thought he was loading this content onto another page via ajax, in which case .live is necessay

Comment: Ah, I see now. I personally still wouldn't use `live()` in that situation, but it would be one approach. Your answer makes more sense to me now. :o)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of submit, use this code

```
<input id='submitMe' type = 'button' value = 'Submit Me' />
```

Now you don't have to
return false;
or
event.preventDefault(); in your javascript

Comment: Incidentally, `<input type="button">` "has been superseded in HTML5 by the `<button>` element." -[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button)