# the div that show() called disappeared in the next second

Tags: javascript, show

When I click the div that suppose to show, it just showed in a second and then disappeared.
How do I make it stay display on the page?

Here is the code

```
<div class="circle0">
<h4><a href="" id="show_1">sketch & drawing</a></h4>
</div>

<div class="sec_down" style="display: none;">
<h1>{Mask}</h1>
</div>

<script>
    $("#show_1").click(function () {
    $(".sec_down").show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Similar question was posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571835/jquery-showing-div-and-then-disappearing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the default click handling in the link so it won't process the href in the link and reload the page.  in jQuery, you can do that by adding `return(false)` to the click handler:

```
<div class="circle0">
<h4><a href="" id="show_1">sketch & drawing</a></h4>
</div>

<div class="sec_down" style="display: none;">
<h1>{Mask}</h1>
</div>

<script>
    $("#show_1").click(function () {
        $(".sec_down").show();
        return(false);   // prevent default handling of the click
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `return(false)` does both `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()` for you in jQuery.  You can code them yourself if you want to, but I find `return(false)` cleaner.  Pick what you like.

Comment: It's not about cleaner, `return false` makes your code more brittle http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/ .

Comment: Per that article, I'm using return(false) exactly when I want it.  I want to prevent default behavior, stop propagation and it's at the end of my function.  Don't see any reason to do it otherwise.  You're free to make a different choice.

Answer (score 0):

Change `href=""` to `href="#"` or break the default action of the link by using `return false`.